# git mergetool cannot find files with international characters

Tags: git, utf-8

> D:\Temp\autohotkey-efficiency>git mergetool 鼠标配合.ahk
>   Merging:
>   "\351\274\240\346\240\207\351\205\215\345\220\210.ahk"
>
> "\351\274\240\346\240\207\351\205\215\345\220\210.ahk": file not found
>   Continue merging other unresolved paths (y/n) ?

I do have 鼠标配合.ahk at this location.

Is git capable of handling international characters or do I have to change any settings?

**Update:**

Setting core.quotepath to false doesn't work.

> D:\Temp\autohotkey-efficiency>git config --global core.quotepath false
>
> D:\Temp\autohotkey-efficiency>git mergetool 鼠标配合.ahk
>   Merging:
>   "\351\274\240\346\240\207\351\205\215\345\220\210.ahk"
>
> "\351\274\240\346\240\207\351\205\215\345\220\210.ahk": file not found
>   Continue merging other unresolved paths (y/n) ?

Comment: Which mergetool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git config --global core.quotepath false
```

Reference: [how to handle asian characters in file names in git on os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144417)

Comment: It doesn't work however. See my update. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @LoveRight `git config -e` to check if there is `[core] quotepath` and what its value is.

Comment: There is [core] section, but no quotepath. I manually added it in. Now the error is `榧犳爣閰嶅悎.ahk: file not found`. The characters are wrong probably related to encoding.

Comment: @LoveRight since the global config would be overwritten by the local config, I was afraid that the local config had core.quotepath as true. I tried it both in Ubuntu and Windows, git version v2.8, merge tool kdiff3 and vimdiff. With core.quotepath false,  cmd like `git log --name-only` outputs the file in its real name. If not false, it's like \351\274.

Comment: @LoveRight that's most probably the key. My locale encoding is utf-8.