# fatal: bad boolean config value 'of' for 'core.quotepath'

Tags: git

Why don't work Git ?
Gives an error message

```
fatal: bad boolean config value 'of' for 'core.quotepath'
```

What should I do to avoid this error message?

Comment: Have you tried removing that config value or changing it to something else?

Comment: `of` is not a boolean value. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38068375/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22core.quotepath%22

Answer (score 3):

Since [Git 2.39, I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39674172/6309) all boolean values are now explicitly described are true or false.

In your case, considering [`core.quotepath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corequotePath) is by default true:

```
git config --global core.quotepath false
```

Or, to restore its default value:

```
git config --global --unset core.quotepath
```

Comment: @VOLGASENATAR I am glad you found this helpful.