# Is it possible for git to display the filename with accents?

Tags: git, internationalization

When I commit, the "Changes to be commited" display my files with the accents escaped:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   "encours/probabilit\303\251_tr\303\250s_faible/avocat_gratuit_pour_une_affaire_par_an/README.me"
#       new file:   "encours/supprimer_vote_bloqu\303\251/README.md"
```

And, it's the same for git status or git diff.

Is there a way to display the accents ?

EDIT: Not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968183) since this solution is for a MacOS specific problem

EDIT 2: I'm on linux / ubuntu

Comment: Looks like this solution is MacOS specific and it's not the same problem

Comment: You haven't named your OS. Still don't, BTW.

Comment: I'm on linux :)

Comment: Solved it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144417/how-to-handle-asian-characters-in-file-names-in-git-on-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle Asian characters in file names in Git on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144417/how-to-handle-asian-characters-in-file-names-in-git-on-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved via [How to handle Asian characters in file names in Git on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144417/how-to-handle-asian-characters-in-file-names-in-git-on-os-x)

```
git config --global core.quotepath false
```